# Angularjs routing fails on server when minification is turned on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, bundling-and-minification

I am currently building a Angularjs singel page application and i have run in to some odd error with my routing.

I have a nav bar with multiple options and all but one of them work correct.

This is my route provider.

```
    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/index", {
            templateUrl: "/App/Views/index.html",
            controller: "IndexController"
        })            
        .when("/log", {
            templateUrl: "/App/Views/log.html",
            controller: "LogController"
        })
        .when("/help", {
            templateUrl: "/App/Views/help.html",
            controller: "HelpController"
        })
        .when("/login", {
            templateUrl: "/App/Views/login.html",
            controller: "LoginController"
        })
        .when("/signup", {
            templateUrl: "/App/Views/signup.html",
            controller: "SignupController"
        })
        .when("/logout", {
            templateUrl: "/App/Views/logout.html",
            controller: "LogOutController"
        })
        .when("/user", {
            templateUrl: "/App/Views/user.html",
            controller: "UserController"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/index"
        });
}]);
```

And this is my Navbar

```
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/index">Hem</a>
                    </li>

                    <li ng-class="{ activeLink: isActive('/log')}" data-ng-hide="!isLoggedIn">
                        <a href="#/log">Logg</a>
                    </li>

                    <li ng-class="{ activeLink: isActive('/help')}" data-ng-hide="!isLoggedIn">
                        <a href="#/help">Hjälp</a>
                    </li>

                    <li ng-class="{ activeLink: isActive('/logout')}" data-ng-hide="!isLoggedIn">
                        <a href="#/logout">Logga ut</a>
                    </li>

                    <li ng-class="{ activeLink: isActive('/user')}" data-ng-hide="!isLoggedIn">
                        <a href="#/user">{{userName}}</a>
                    </li>
```

And my problem is that when i click the {{userName}} link i am taken to the index page.

And this error only occurs on the live server when the js is minified, if it is unminified on the server so does it work like intended.
If i run this site localy i can use both the regular version and the minified one and the routing behaves like intended.
The console does not show any errors when i click on the link and whn i inspect the html in chrome so does it have the correct html

```
     <a href="#/user" class="ng-binding">Johan Karlsson</a>.
```

I have tried pointing the {{userName}} link to "#/log" and it worked fine.

Here is my user controller

```
(function () {

var app = angular.module("connectPortal");

var userController = ['$scope', 'authService', function ($scope, authService) {

    authService.authenticateUser();

    $scope.var = "var variable from HelpController";
}];

app.controller("UserController", userController);

}());
```

And this is my log controller

```
(function () {

var app = angular.module("connectPortal");

var logController = ['$scope', 'authService', function ($scope, authService) {

    authService.authenticateUser();

    $scope.var = "var variable from LogController";

}];

app.controller("LogController", logController);

}());
```

Comment: Do you have a working demo of your problem? E.g. make a jsfiddle or jsbin with your minified and unminified code, so people could see the difference.

Comment: It is a rather large application that is being run on top a MVC ASP .NET applikation so a jsFiddle might take some time.
(The code that i am showing has been abbreviated slightly)

Comment: FWIW I've had cases where using the `$location` service (trigger by `ng-click`) was the only way to safely navigate to a page. It's pretty hard to tell what exactly is wrong here without being hands-on with the code, and if you produce a fiddle you might not even be able to reproduce. If I faced this problem I would try to remove things untill it stops not working, probably starting with the authService. Keep stripping away parts untill the problem goes away and you should be able to identify the culprit eventually.